# When modifying a Session used in subscription, template is fully recomputed instead of just add new datas

Tags: meteor

In my project i have a route that display a list of content.
Content is retreived by a subription and depends on 3 Session var.
At the begining i get 12 items in content. I have a pager that allow to get more data by modifying one of the Session dependency. 
But when i do it, the list of content if completly removed and then fully re-rendered.

I tried to have a look inside the app with debugger. It seems that it is in Tracker.flush() method (from Tracker.js meteor file) that it happens.

```
  while (pendingComputations.length) {
    var comp = pendingComputations.shift();
    comp._recompute(); // HERE IT WILL REMOVE ALL ITEMS AND THEN ADD ALL FROM THE SUBSCRIPTION
  }
```

In fact it should just add new items to the template, and not remove them all and then adding them all again with new ones.

I use Iron Router, my app is on 0.9.3.1 (upgrade from 0.8.x).

[edit] precision about what i mean by "re-render" :
the list of items is completely removed from the template 
and then the list appear again with old items and new items
because i do step-by-step debugging i cn say that when list template is cleared, in console i still have access to items collection, and the count on that collection returns me a number greater than 0

[edit] about a reproduction project
I'm working on, and i hope i'll be able to understand the problem to explain it. It's available here http://displaybugreproductionwithironrouterprogess.meteor.com
And source code is here https://github.com/Rebolon/meteor-ironrouterprogress-bug
If you just do a

```
meteor remove mrt:iron-router-progress
```

then the app runs correctly and the template is not fully re-rendered (so there is no clipping at the screen).

Comment: Meteor 0.9.x is generally pretty good about not re-rendering, so it might be a good idea to post a reproduction (a repo to github which exibits the behavior you don't want).

Comment: You might also want to be more clear about what you mean by 're-render', are you using some jquery to animate the changes? Or what is happening on re-render that you don't like. There are some quirks about the way that `each` tags are handled (as opposed to `with` tags) which might be responsible for the issue your seeing.

Comment: I'm doing a simple app to reproduce the problem and it seems that packahe mrt:iron-router-progress is the source of the problem. I still don't know why, but without the package it works. Still investigating

Comment: I think your on the right track for finding out what's going on. I suspect that the iron-router-progress package is causing the template to change somehow, if a new template is being inserted it will cause the whole template to be rendered.